# Aws local zone vs Edge locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cdn

Is it okay to say local zones are an extension of edge locations as they both focus on bringing services closer to the end-user. With local zones allowing more services such ec2 instances and edge locations focusing on CDN and route53

Answer (score 3):

No. Edge Locations are used for Amazon Route 53, Amazon CloudFront and AWS Lambda@Edge. They are located in places *outside* of regions.

I think of Local Zones as Availability Zone that are outside of the Region's normal geographic description. Normally, all AZs belonging to a region are within a particular distance of each other. A Local Zone is *outside* of that distance, sort of 'attaching' itself to a more-distant region. It's a way that AWS can provide more geographic coverage without having to create yet another multi-AZ region (which is rather expensive!).

Answer (score 1):

Typical AWS edge locations (such as those used for CloudFront content delivery networks world wide) may or may not be located in the same geographical area or metro as a Local Zone. It is correct what John Rotenstein said - LZs are extensions of their parent region. It's basically infrastructure we physically deploy in a specific metro location, and where metadata and control plane data flows back and forth to the parent region - but the services run locally.

And because the services themselves (such as EKS, ECS, EC2 instances) are physically deployed closer to your end-users (let's say in Houston), they experience a lower latency between themselves and the Local Zone vs. consuming those same services from the parent region (ex. us-east-1, Northern Virginia). This is especially important for workloads such as gaming, financial services, and even migration uses for customers present in Texas, etc.

Even Glemmestad, Principle BusDev Mgr. for AWS Local Zones

Answer (score 0):

Mainly edge location is used to host the web content (Static or Dynamic) it may be in the form of Cache or the uploaded one by a user while local zone is mainly used for infrastructure deployment that places compute, storage, database, and other selected AWS services close to large population. Means Edge locations might be small centers while local zone are bigger one so that it can provide the compute powers based on deployed infrastructure in this zone.

Comment: Thanks ,now i understand. After further research i find out that local zones are actually an extension of Availability zones, they are established closer to end users narrow the distance between availability zones and users.

Answer (score 0):

Following can be shown as the difference between Edge Locations and Local Zones.

**AWS Edge Locations:**

Edge locations are endpoints for AWS which are used for caching content and used as Content delivery network (CDN).

Requests going to either one of these services will be routed to the nearest edge location automatically. This allows for low latency no matter where the end user is located.

**AWS Local Zones:**

AWS Local Zones allow you to use select AWS services, like compute and storage services, closer to more end-users, providing them very low latency access to the applications running locally.

Applications which require single-digit millisecond latencies to your end-users, latency-sensitive applications

In Simple terms, AWS Local Zones are a type of infrastructure deployment that places compute, storage, database, and other select AWS services close to large population and industry centers.

*Use Cases:*

- Run low-latency applications at the edge
- Simplify hybrid cloud migrations
- Meet stringent data residency requirements